# Why doesn't rm() work on paste0() string?

Tags: r, rm

I tried removing data from my environment using `rm(paste0("namePart1", "namePart2"))`, but got the " ... must contain names or character strings" error. However, when I changed it to `rm(list=paste0("namePart1", "namePart2"))` or `rm("namePart1namePart2")` the problem disappeared. What is the difference?

Comment: Wanting to remove dynamically created names is almost certainly a mistake, and points to other problems in your code. In general, you *should not* dynamically generate names. Use named lists instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the documentation of [`rm`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rm.html), last paragraph of section Details, my emphasis.

> Earlier versions of R incorrectly claimed that supplying a character vector in ... removed the **objects** named in the character vector, but it removed the **character vector**. Use the list argument to specify objects via a character vector.

### 1. Pass the variables' names as character strings one by one.

No errors are thrown, the objects `x1`, `x2` and `x3` were removed from the `.GlobalEnv`.

```r
x1 <- 1
x2 <- 2
x3 <- 3

rm(x1)         # or rm("x1")
rm(x2, x3)     # or rm("x2", "x3")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### 2. Pass a character vector containing the objects' names.

What is removed is the vector `vec`, the objects whose names it used to contain still exist in the `.GlobalEnv`.

```r
x1 <- 1
x2 <- 2
x3 <- 3
vec <- c("x2", "x3")

rm("vec")

x1
#> [1] 1
x2
#> [1] 2
x3
#> [1] 3

vec
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'vec' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### 3. Dynamically create names of objects to be removed.

Functions `paste` and `paste0` both return vectors and for the documented reasons above `rm` doesn't remove objects with names returned by a function, it tries to remove the character vector but it cannot because the dots argument only accepts unquoted names or character strings naming objects.

The users need to dynamically create names of objects to be removed is predicted and that's why argument `list` exists. In order to remove the objects, not the vector containing their names, use `list = vec`. Now `vec` can be the output of a function such as `paste`, `paste0` or `ls`.

```r
x1 <- 1
x2 <- 2
x3 <- 3

paste0("x", 1:3)
#> [1] "x1" "x2" "x3"

rm(paste0("x", 1:3))
#> Error in rm(paste0("x", 1:3)):  
#>   ... must contain names or character strings

rm(list = paste0("x", 1:3))

x1
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'x1' not found
x2
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'x2' not found
x3
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'x3' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @KonradRudolph You are right, thanks for the tip. I have changed the code to show both ways, the unquoted names version and the quoted names version in comments.